# How to get array element by passing another array element ?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array follow

```
[0] => Array
 (
    [month] => Oct
    [amount] => 1200.00
 )
```

and how do i get `[amount]` by passing `[month]`

Comment: You have to either iterate over the array and search for the month value or convert your array to `month => amount` for direct access.

Comment: Yes, you have to use a loop. The datastructure is unfortunate for that. If you can change it, this would be the best option.

Answer (score 6):

You don't. Two options:

1. Loop:

   ```
   foreach ($array as $i) {
        if ($i['month'] == 'Oct') {
            echo $i['amount'];
        }
   }
   ```
2. Index the data by month:

   ```
   $array = array_combine(array_map(function($i) { return $i['month']; }, $array),
                          $array);
   echo $array['Oct']['amount'];
   ```

Comment: The second option would only work if the month for each entry is unique. You could always create a `month => [amount, ...]` map, but that's a bit more complex. Just pointing it out :), it should be enough to get the OP started.

Comment: Totally correct, obviously I'm working on assumptions here... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    if ($v['month'] == $needleMonth) {
        echo $v['amount'] . ' - that`s it';
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop your array and test each time if your wanted month == $arrayElement[$i]['month']

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) {
    if ($v['month']=='Oct') {
        echo $v['amount'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$selectedMonth = 'Oct';

foreach($yourArray as $child){

    if($child['month'] == $selectedMonth){
        echo $child['amount'];
    }

}
```